# Stop executing JQuery function before start the same function

Tags: javascript, jquery

> There is common problem when user click faster than action can finish.

In front end, there is **edit button** on **X** rows. When user clicks on one row, js trigger this function.

```
$('.edit').click(function () {
    var id = $(this).attr('data-id');
    $('#registrantDetails').load("/dashboard/edit-conference-registration/" + id + "/{{ confName }}")
}}
```

But after click again, second action wait for first to finish etc.

I wanted to ask how to stop **.load()** function before start another one?

Comment: Add a flag for `isProcessing` and if its true, just return

Comment: You can disabled button and re-enable it from `load()` complete callback

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just add varible to handle when this's working.

```
var isWorking = false;
$('.edit').click(function () {
     if (isWorking) return;
     isWorking = true;
     var id = $(this).attr('data-id');
     $('#registrantDetails').load("/dashboard/edit-conference-registration/" + id + "/{{ confName }}");
     isWorking = false;
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
$('.edit').click(function () {
    var id = $(this).attr('data-id');
    $('#registrantDetails').unbind('load'); 
    $('#registrantDetails').load("/dashboard/edit-conference-registration/" + id +   "/{{ confName }}")
}}
```